# Retrieving accidently deleted files in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I used rm -rf * command and all my files and documents in the computer got deleted.
I want to retrieve them back.
So, which software should I use to retrieve them back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva)

Comment: it is available for ubuntu as well

Answer (score 0):

You can try [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) which can sometimes recover recently deleted files.
[extundelete](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/) is another tool which is really great if your file system is ext3 or ext4